# Do .sav files expire after the trial version expires?

Tags: statistics

I saved a certain file on an SPSS software that expires after 2 weeks of its installation. I wanted to ask if my file would still exist even after the expiration date. The data is for psychology research.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between **[trial software](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-does-trial-software-version-work)** and the 'real' thing is that trial software looses some or all functions after the trial period. Any files generated with it will be kept and be functional; only the exe file is affected. The company of course hopes that you wish to use those files after the trial period and buy the full license.